# Why doesn't presenceOfElementLocated timeout after 2 seconds as specified in wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have this code:

```
public static boolean isWebElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By byExpression) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    try { 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(byExpression));
        return true;
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        //System.out.println("Webelement is not present under this expression " + byExpression);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The wait.until call takes approx. 20 seconds until the timeout is catched. My question is why doesn't this method call timeout after 2 seconds which I specified in the WebDriverWait above? what does the wait do in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an implicit wait set?

Comment: That's your issue then. The `presenceOfElementLocated` method will eventually call `findElement` which would use the implict wait. So it's going to sit there for 15 seconds waiting for that element to appear. Once the 15 seconds are up, the control is given back to the `WebDriverWait` where it will say "this took 15 seconds which is longer than 2 seconds, so throw an exception". You must lower your implicit wait.

Comment: Yes now I get it, thanks